# Set Thymeleaf language using session attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am failing to solve a seemingly easy problem.

- Whenever a session is opened (`session.user_lang` is null), English is used as the default language (messages.properties). A (registered) user can change the language in which case the language is saved to the session attribute (`session.user_lang`) and to the database.
- Thymeleaf should check `session.user_lang` and translate based on that value.

I couldn't get it to work for a long time. I have tried defining

```java
@Component
public class LocaleInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

    @Autowired
    public void setLocaleResolver(LocaleResolver localeResolver) {
        this.localeResolver = localeResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String language = (String) session.getAttribute("user_lang");
        if (language != null) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, locale);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private LocaleInterceptor localeInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public void setLocaleInterceptor(LocaleInterceptor localeInterceptor) {
        this.localeInterceptor = localeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting language session in spring boot or thymeleaf(html)? You set session in spring boot using setAttribute () and read it in html-thymeleaf using session.session_name

Comment: I am setting the language of the client in spring boot. I want thymeleaf to read that variable (XX) and translate HTML that is generated for the client based on that variable (messages_XX.properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides several implementations of the [`LocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html) one of them is the [`SessionLocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html). The `SessionLocaleResolver` uses, as the name implies, the `HttpSession` to store the `Locale` to be used. Just what you want. So instead of writing your own, you can simply use the `SessionLocaleResolver`.

```java
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
  SessionLocaleResolver localResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
  localeResolver.setLocaleAttributeName("user_locale"); // Not strictly needed
  localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
  return localResolver;
};
```

The `SessionLocaleResolver` also allows the `Locale` to be changed by the user (if desired). You can achieve this by configuring the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` which will, when requested, store the new `Locale` in the `HttpSession` (it actually delegates this to the `LocaleResolver` that is configured).

All in all there is no need to write custom code all is supported out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

The following Bean solved the problem:

```java
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    return new LocaleResolver() {
        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String lang = (String) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, "user_lang");
        return (lang != null) ? new Locale(lang) : Locale.ENGLISH;
        }

        @Override
        public void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {
        }
    };
    }
```

Comment: Just add the `SessionLocaleResolver` instead of writing your own. That together with the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` should give you all you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you post this as an answer, please?