# MessageSource not using the same locale as Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization, locale

I set user locale based on the session attribute.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan
@Configuration
public class Webapp {

    // Thymeleaf
    @Bean
    public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
    return new LayoutDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setLocaleAttributeName("user_locale"); // Not strictly needed
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:lang/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Webapp.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I use Thymeleaf template, everything with `#{..}` gets translated via messages_XX.properties based on the correct language XX (which is specified in the session attribute). However, `messageSource.getMessage(text, null, null)` always returns English. How can I fix this? I do not even know where to start debugging.

Comment: Does this help [set-thymeleaf-language-using-session-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76775442/set-thymeleaf-language-using-session-attribute/76777259)

Comment: @DirkDeyne updated. Unfortunately, no. MessageSource gives the default language when used with `null` argument, Thymeleaf gives the correct language.

Comment: Which is as designed. If you don't pass in the `Locale` it will resort to `Locale.getDefault()` which gets the default for your JDK. It will not use the `LocaleResolver` or `LocalContextHolder` to resolve the locale. If you want to use the configured locale use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` to get the one from the user (if any specified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue you can retrieve the current locale from the LocaleContext associated with the current thread. For example in the controller like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public String showUserList(Model model) {
        Locale currentLocale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        log.info("Current locale: {}", currentLocale);
        model.addAttribute("customers", customerService.getCustomers());
        return "customers";
    }
```

You can then pass the locale to the messageSource:

```
messageSource.getMessage(text, null, currentLocale)
```

Comment: Use `LocalContextHolder.getLocale()` instead or just inject the `Locale` into the method. Don't make it more complex then that.